# Auto suggest number using best search algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

My problem statement is :

Dropdown contains 3 categories: r1, r2, r3, where:

1 < r1 < 4000 , 4000 < r2 < 10000, 10000 < r3 < 29372830130.

If the user chooses 'x' (r1 or r2 or r3) then, a search has to be done from the existing values if present or not, if not it has to suggest one within the range to the user. Which algorithm should I prefer a Binary search tree or which algorithm is efficient(time complexity)? My code stack is JS.

Note: ranges are very high.

Comment: You say "a search has to be done in DB" - so you don't need to implement any search algorithm yourself, you just have to ask the database?

Comment: I edited the question ...can you please check now

Comment: How many "existing vales" are present on average? How are they stored, in what data structure?

Comment: maximum values can range up to 1 lakh . Existing values are stored in 1-d array

Comment: Give an example

Comment: Yes, store them sorted, use binary search.

Comment: Why store them? Just keep min and Max values

Comment: I am using Binary search tree to do this...is there any better algorithm to solve this problem ?

Comment: @vivek_23  , user knows about min and max values but he is not aware if the value is taken or not .For this , i need a search algorithm

Comment: @SrikanthTunuguntla please show a proper working example by editing your post

Comment: I agree with @Bergi, binary search is the answer (binary search tree is the same)

Comment: Are you saying that if the user chooses `123`, then you would search `r1` to see if that value exists. If so, you display it. And if not, then you "suggest" some value that is between 2 and 4000? On what basis do you choose the value to suggest? A concrete example would be very useful, because it is not at all clear what you're asking.